# Midday (noon) and midnight in refering to 12 o’clock during the day / night

Tags: розмовна-українська, числівники, позначення-часу

These numerals in an answers to a questions with **When** may be in following cases:

> - Потяг прибуває **опівдні**.
> - Новорічний салют запускают **опівночі**.

But what case of that numerals we should use for an answers to a questions with **What** e.g.

> Котра година?

Comment: _Котра_ is more _which_ than _what_.

Comment: Why wouldn't you look up those words in a dictionary? _Noon_ – «полудень, південь», _midnight_ – «північ», these words are pretty suitable as answers to "What time is it?"

Comment: @YellowSky is ukrainian midnight «північ» the same as "north" or these two words are just homonyms?

Comment: As for me, it's the same word with two meanings, just like _захід_ also has two meanings: 1. sunset; 2. west.

Comment: @YellowSky ye, but google tells me that «захід» as sunset is obsolete. Now we should use «захід сонця» instead.